# nodej.s how to check if 2 cheerio (xml) objects are equal

Tags: node.js, xml, cheerio

I'm using node.js cheerio module to parse a XML configuration file. I load this file periodically from my server to update the configuration.

How can I check if the old configuration is exactly the same as the new one, so I won't need to process it?

I tried using something like:

`JSON.stringify(cheerioObj) === JSON.stringify(newCheerioObj)`

but stringify actually returns `undefined` on that object (it only has functions I guess..)

I see there is access to raw XML data: `cheerioObj.xml()` so I could compare these 2 strings, but what if the new xml has exactly the same configuration and only  differs in some whitespace that doesn't affect the data at all? That's why I'd prefer to compare stringified objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the normalizeWhitespace option when loading the xml data. You can also trim the input strings for some extra robustness:

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const xml1 = '<config><element1 id="1">42</element1><element2 id="2">101</element2></config>';
const cheerioObj1 = cheerio.load(xml1.trim(), {
    xml: {
        normalizeWhitespace: true,
    }
});

const xml2 = '      <config><element1 id="1" >42</element1><element2 id="2"    >101</element2></config>';
const cheerioObj2 = cheerio.load(xml2.trim(), {
    xml: {
        normalizeWhitespace: true,
    }
});

console.log("Comparison result: ", cheerioObj1.xml() === cheerioObj2.xml());
```